# Segmentation fault with dynamically allocated arrays as members of structure in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I am writing a program using an array of structures to store a name, id number, and an array of test scores for a certain amount of students. Both the array of structures and the array of test scores member need to be dynamically allocated. I've gotten down to the function that allows the user to input test scores for each student, however I am having problems with the cin in the last function (getScores function). When using Linux I get a segmentation fault, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the dynamically allocated tests array that is a member of the structure, I just can't see it. I'm wondering how I can go about debugging it and an explanation of why this is actually occurring so I can avoid it in the future.

```
//Preprocessor Directives
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Structure declaration
struct Students
{
    string name; //Student name
    int idNum; //Student ID number
    double *tests; //Pointer to an array of test scores
};

//Function prototypes
Students *getStudents(int &);
double *getTests(int &);
void getInfo(string &, int &, int);
void getScores(double &, string, int);

//Main program section
int main ()
{
    int numStudents = 0;
    int numTests = 0;
    Students *studentFiles = NULL;

    //Call the getStudents function
    studentFiles = getStudents(numStudents);

    //Call the getTests function
    studentFiles->tests = getTests(numTests);

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        //Call the getInfo function
        getInfo(studentFiles[i].name, studentFiles[i].idNum, i+1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numTests; j++)
        {
            getScores(studentFiles[i].tests[j], studentFiles[i].name, j);
        }
    }
    delete [] studentFiles;
    delete [] studentFiels->tests;
    return 0;
}

Students *getStudents(int &numStudents)
{
    Students *studentFiles = NULL;

    //Prompt the user for the number of students
    cout<<"Enter the number of students: ";
    cin>>numStudents;
    //Dynamically allocate an array of structs, one for each student
    studentFiles = new Students[numStudents];

    return studentFiles;
}

double *getTests(int &numTests)
{
    double *tests = NULL;

    //Prompt the user for the number of tests
    cout<<"Enter the number of tests: ";
    cin>>numTests;
    cin.ignore();
    //Dynamicall allocate an array of integers, one for each test 
    tests = new double[numTests];

    return tests;
}

void getInfo(string &name, int &idNum, int index)
{
    //Prompt for each student's name and id number
    cout<<"Enter the name of student #"<<index<<": ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<"Enter the id number of student #"<<index<<": ";
    cin>>idNum;
    cin.ignore();
}

void getScores(double &test, string name, int numTest)
{
    cout<<name<<endl;
    cout<<numTest<<endl;
    //Prompt for each test score for each student
    cout<<"Enter "<<name<<"'s score for test #"<<numTest+1<<": ";
    cin>>test;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? What did you see when you did? Where does it crash, what are the memory values, ...

Comment: It crashes whenever there is more than one student, right after the last cin in the getScores function. It seems like it isn't reading that last value in because maybe there's no where to put it or something, but I don't understand why. If i enter 2 students 2 tests it goes through the first two test scores for the first student. When it gets the entering the test score for the second student you can type the score, press enter, then it crashes. That's where Linux gave me the segmentation fault.

Comment: `studentFiles->tests = getTests(numTests);` - `studentFiles` is a pointer to an array in your code, but here you are dereferencing it like it was a pointer to a single element -> only your first `Student` object has a valid `tests` pointer, every other one doesn't (so you get *undefined behavior*)

Comment: @UnholySheep Ok that does make sense because it works if there is only one student. How to do I make each `Student` object have a valid tests pointer?

Comment: you need to iterate over all `Students` object and assign each `tests` a valid pointer (e.g. using your `getTests` function)

Comment: Again: use std::vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One error is that you access a member of deleted object `studentFiles`. Reverse the lines to fix that:

```
delete [] studentFiles->tests;    
delete [] studentFiles;
```

Ideally, use `std::vector<>` instead of dynamically allocating and releasing memory manually.

Also note, that the code only initializes `Student::tests` of the first member of the array, the rest of `Student` objects have this member uninitialized. The result of expression `studentFiles[i].tests[j]` is undefined and is likely to cause a crash.

You need to initialize `Student::tests` member of each `Student`. And when done, deallocate `Student::tests` of each `Student`.

Comment: +1 for the `std::vector` suggestion. Using proper RAII also helps ensure that objects are properly destroyed in reverse order of their declaration, as was the problem here

Comment: That does not seem to have solved the problem, and we just have covered dynamic memory allocation so I don't know how to use the other solution you offered yet.

Comment: @mobandy644 Added a note about `Student::tests`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thank you that does make sense now, is there a way to create each 'Student' object's test member so that the program will work?

Comment: @mobandy644 Your program misses loops to initialize each student and each test.